# Cardiod-like curve traced by bottom-most point of circle rotating around outer circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, polar-coordinates, plane-curves

Is there a name /any references for the curve traced out by point $C$ in the following gif?
[image: parametric curve]

Specifically, let $r$ and $R$ denote the radius of the inner and outer circles. Let $P$ denote the center of the inner circle, and $d = R - r$ denote the distance from the origin to center of the smaller circle.

Suppose the center of the smaller circle $P$ moves along the following curve parametrized by $t$,
\begin{equation}
    P(t) = ( d \cos(t), \; d \sin(t) )
\end{equation}

Then, I'm interested in the curve traced out by $C$ for the -y direction, then reflected along the x axis for the +y direction.
This looks like the purple curve in the image below.
[image]

Is there a name for this curve / any references for this? Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulette_(curve)

Comment: Did you find the equation of your Roulette?

Comment: Hint: The point $C$ traces (an arc of) a circle